# TabHost and Android 4.0 ICS

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have searched for this for a long time now... I am writing an App which should be compatible between Android 2.2 and Android 4.0.
Since under Android 4.0 Tabs are deprecated I was wondering what would be the right way to do it? If I still use Tabs as in my testings they look quite nice (All the same size, no icons...) but if I then run it on a 2.2 they all look pressed together (just the size of the title each tab has, maybe has to do with me using a HorizontalScrollView?)
What would be the right decision here?
Just using tabs for Android 2.2 and 4.0? And if yes how can I set the Tabs on 2.2 to be all the same size?
Use Fragments on 4.0 and Tabs on 2.2? And if yes how would I implement this?
If I should use Tabs should I only use 4 Tabs (I have between 2 and 10 - dynamically) and put an extra "More" Tab? If yes how would I do that?

I hope the question is understandable. If not feel free to ask for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check out [ActionBarSherlock](http://abs.io/) - it provides the nice new ICS tabs for Android 2.1+ and has perfect samples.

Comment: Wanted to try this a long time ago already... I will try it out thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. It's a great tool to create compatible apps :)

Comment: Wow it really is... Just installed the Demo Apps from Play Store... Really is absolutely awesome! Thanks again I surely think now I will use ActionBarSherlock for the App!

Answer (score 0):

try this one code

```
public class WebMenu extends TabActivity {
    //Intent intent;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tebmenu);

        Resources res = getResources();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Add_webpage.class);
        spec = tabHost
                .newTabSpec("Add new Web Page")
                .setIndicator("New",
                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.folder_web_blue))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WebHistory.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Web History")
                .setIndicator("History", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.webhistory))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WebList.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Web List")
                .setIndicator("List", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.weblist))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
But i don't think you understood it the right way. I already have my code written. I have my Tabs etc. I was wondering which is the right way?